# Kubernetes: how to scale my pods

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes. I try to scale my pods. First I started 3 pods:

```
./cluster/kubectl.sh run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3 --port=80
```

There were starting 3 pods. First I tried to scale up/down by using a replicationcontroller but this did not exist. It seems to be a replicaSet now.

```
./cluster/kubectl.sh get rs
NAME                  DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
my-nginx-2494149703   3         3         9h
```

I tried to change the amount of replicas described in my replicaset:

```
./cluster/kubectl.sh scale --replicas=5 rs/my-nginx-2494149703
replicaset "my-nginx-2494149703" scaled
```

But I still see my 3 original pods

```
./cluster/kubectl.sh get pods
NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-nginx-2494149703-04xrd   1/1       Running   0          9h
my-nginx-2494149703-h3krk   1/1       Running   0          9h
my-nginx-2494149703-hnayu   1/1       Running   0          9h
```

I would expect to see 5 pods.

```
./cluster/kubectl.sh describe rs/my-nginx-2494149703
Name:       my-nginx-2494149703
Namespace:  default
Image(s):   nginx
Selector:   pod-template-hash=2494149703,run=my-nginx
Labels:     pod-template-hash=2494149703
        run=my-nginx
Replicas:   3 current / 3 desired
Pods Status:    3 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
```

Why isn't it scaling up? Do I also have to change something in the deployment?

I see something like this when I describe my rs after scaling up:
(Here I try to scale from one running pod to 3 running pods). But it remains one running pod. The other 2 are started and killed immediatly

```
  34s       34s     1   {replicaset-controller }            Normal      SuccessfulCreate    Created pod: my-nginx-1908062973-lylsz
  34s       34s     1   {replicaset-controller }            Normal      SuccessfulCreate    Created pod: my-nginx-1908062973-5rv8u
  34s       34s     1   {replicaset-controller }            Normal      SuccessfulDelete    Deleted pod: my-nginx-1908062973-lylsz
  34s       34s     1   {replicaset-controller }            Normal      SuccessfulDelete    Deleted pod: my-nginx-1908062973-5rv8u
```

Comment: Actually it seems you did everything right .. Have a look to the events if there is something strange that happened (kubectl.sh get events)

Comment: I've added some events I saw when I read the description of my rs

Comment: Scaling the deployment works. I read it's recommended to scale your deployment. But okay, normally it has to work

Comment: yep, in my configuration both scale  deployment and scale rs work .. did you try to scale the deployment? Same result?

Comment: As I said, scaling deployment works, scaling rs doesn't :/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

TL;DR: You need to scale your deployment instead of the replica set directly.

If you try to scale the replica set, then it will (for a very short time) have a new count of 5. But the deployment controller will see that the current count of the replica set is 5 and since it knows that it is supposed to be 3, it will reset it back to 3. By manually modifying the replica set that was created for you, you are fighting with the system controller (which is untiring and will pretty much always outlast you).

Comment: I'm unable to see my RC (only RS). Is that normal?

Comment: And how am I able to create an autoscaler now? Also with deployment?

Comment: Deployment will create a replica set (rs), *not* a replication controller (rc). So only seeing output from `kubectl get rs` is expected.

Comment: What kind of autoscaler are you trying to use?

Comment: first I tried to do something like: kubectl autoscale rs.. but the new pod ware deleted immediatley (probably because I don't have a RC). So now I did: kubectl autoscale deployment ...

Comment: Trying to enable autoscaling on your replica set will put you in the same situation as manually scaling the replica set -- except now you will have two controllers fighting instead of you fighting with a controller. Enabling autoscaling on the deployment using `kubectl autoscale deployment` is the right way to add horizontal pod autoscaling to your nginx pods.

Answer (score 63):

This is working for me

```
kubectl scale --replicas=<expected_replica_num> deployment <deployment_label_name> -n <namespace>
```

Example

```
# kubectl scale --replicas=3 deployment xyz -n my_namespace
```

Answer (score 22):

`kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3 --port=80` in this `kubectl run` will create a **deployment** or **job** to manage the created container(s).
**Deployment-->ReplicaSet-->Pod** this is how kubernetes works.
If you change the *bottom-level* object, its *higher-level* object will undo your change.You have to change the *top-level* object.

[image]

Comment: worth to mention, that HPA config with min/max replica values can rollback scaling of either deployment or replica set as well.

Answer (score 11):

scale it down to zero and then to the number of pods you required (guess it equals to 3)

```
kubectl scale deployment <deployment-name> --replicas=0 -n <namespace>
kubectl scale deployment <deployment-name> --replicas=3 -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 3):

for **deployment**

```
kubectl scale deployment <deployment-name> --replicas=3 -n <namespace>
```

for **statefulset**

```
kubectl scale statefulsets <stateful-set-name> --replicas=3 -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best way as I'm starting out with kubernetes, but I did this by updating my yaml file

```
# app.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
...
spec:
  replicas: <new value>
```

and running `$ kubectl scale -f app.yaml --replicas=<new value>`

you can verify your new number of replicas by running `$ kubectl get pods`

In my case I was also interested in scaling back my VMs, on google cloud. I did this with `$ gcloud container clusters resize appName --size=1 --zone "my-zone"`

Answer (score 1):

Below example shows how you should scale up/down your "pods/resource/deployments".

```
k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ more createdeb_deployment1.yaml 


--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: debdeploy-webserver
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: debdeploy1webserver
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: debdeploy1webserver
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          image: "docker.io/debu3645/debapachewebserver:v1"
          name: deb-deploy1-container 
          ports: 
            - 
              containerPort: 6060
```

deployment created -->

```
**kubectl -n debns1 create -f createdeb_deployment1.yaml**




k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ `kubectl scale --replicas=5 **deployment**/debdeploy-webserver -n debns1`
```

(Scale up 5 deployments)

```
k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ kubectl get pods -n debns1


NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-8wvzx   1/1     Running   0          16s
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-jrf6v   1/1     Running   0          16s
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-m9fpw   1/1     Running   0          16s
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-q9n7r   1/1     Running   0          16s
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-ttw6p   1/1     Running   1          19h
resourcepod-deb1                       1/1     Running   5          6d18h




k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ **kubectl get ep -n debns1**



NAME                ENDPOINTS                                                     AGE
frontend-svc-deb    192.168.1.10:80,192.168.1.11:80,192.168.1.12:80 + 2 more...   18h
frontend-svc1-deb   192.168.1.8:80                                                14d
frontend-svc2-deb   192.168.1.8:80                                                5d19h




k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ **kubectl scale --replicas=2** deployment/debdeploy-webserver -n debns1
```

(***Scale down from 5 to 2***)

deployment.extensions/debdeploy-webserver scaled

```
k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ **kubectl get pods -n debns1**


NAME                                   READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-8wvzx   1/1     Terminating   0          35m
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-jrf6v   1/1     Terminating   0          35m
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-m9fpw   1/1     Terminating   0          35m
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-q9n7r   1/1     Running       0          35m
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-ttw6p   1/1     Running       1          19h
resourcepod-deb1                       1/1     Running       5          6d19h


k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ **kubectl get pods -n debns1**


NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-q9n7r   1/1     Running   0          37m
debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-ttw6p   1/1     Running   1          19h
resourcepod-deb1                       1/1     Running   5          6d19h

k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ kubectl **scale --current-replicas=4 --replicas=2** deployment/debdeploy-webserver -n debns1  (Check the current no. of deployments. If current replication is 4, then bring it down to 2, else dont do anything)


error: Expected replicas to be 4, was 2


k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ **kubectl scale --current-replicas=3 --replicas=10 deployment/debdeploy-webserver -n debns1**


error: Expected replicas to be 3, was 2


k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ **kubectl scale --current-replicas=2 --replicas=10 deployment/debdeploy-webserver -n debns1**
```

deployment.extensions/debdeploy-webserver scaled

```
k8smaster@k8smaster:~/debashish$ **kubectl get pods -n debns1**


    NAME                                   READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-46bxg   1/1     Running             0          6s
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-d6qsx   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6s
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-fdq6v   1/1     Running             0          6s
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-gd87t   1/1     Running             0          6s
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-kqdbj   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6s
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-q9n7r   1/1     Running             0          47m
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-qjvm6   1/1     Running             0          6s
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-skxq4   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6s
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-ttw6p   1/1     Running             1          19h
    debdeploy-webserver-7cf4fb74c5-wlc7q   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          6s
    resourcepod-deb1                       1/1     Running             5          6d19h
```

Comment: The formatting of this answer needs to be improved. Use the code formatting to distinguish commands/code from the rest of your answer

Answer (score 0):

### Autoscaling

All answers are referring to manual scaling and interaction with `kubectl`. 
It is also worth to mention the option of HPA ([Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)).

#### In general

> In Kubernetes, a HorizontalPodAutoscaler automatically updates a
> workload resource (such as a Deployment or StatefulSet), with the aim of
> automatically scaling the workload to match demand.
>
> Horizontal scaling means that the response to increased load is to
> deploy more Pods. This is different from vertical scaling, which for
> Kubernetes would mean assigning more resources (for example: memory or
> CPU) to the Pods that are already running for the workload.
>
> If the load decreases, and the number of Pods is above the configured
> minimum, the HorizontalPodAutoscaler instructs the workload resource
> (the Deployment, StatefulSet, or other similar resource) to scale back
> down.
>
> Horizontal pod autoscaling does not apply to objects that can't be
> scaled (for example: a DaemonSet.)
>
> The HorizontalPodAutoscaler is implemented as a Kubernetes API
> resource and a controller. The resource determines the behavior of the
> controller. The horizontal pod autoscaling controller, running within
> the Kubernetes control plane, periodically adjusts the desired scale
> of its target (for example, a Deployment) to match observed metrics
> such as average CPU utilization, average memory utilization, or any
> other custom metric you specify.

#### Common usage

The common use for HorizontalPodAutoscaler is to configure it to fetch metrics from aggregated APIs (`metrics.k8s.io`, `custom.metrics.k8s.io`, or `external.metrics.k8s.io`).

The `metrics.k8s.io` API is usually provided by an add-on named Metrics Server, which needs to be launched separately. 
For more information about resource metrics, see [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server).

#### Example

An example for scaling on CPU and Memory policy:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: nginx
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 100Mi
```

Read about the [Configurable scaling behavior](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#configurable-scaling-behavior).

---

Additional information:

1. Ensure you're using `apiVersion: autoscaling/v2`.
2. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#scaling-on-custom-metrics) that you can also scale on Custom Metrics.
3. In case you need to scale from/to 0 or scale according to some Cloud resources metrics (like AWS SQS, GCP pub/Sub or other services), Kafka, Redis and other - read about [Keda](https://keda.sh/).